# Why might one function run in SQL Server CLR cause a crash, while working fine in a standalone app?

Tags: sql-server, sqlclr

These two methods below are similar, except one handles null values and the other does not.  To handle null values, it uses SqlString type and checks the "get_IsNull" property.

Why might the first one be causing the error `"A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user-defined routine or aggregate "CheckMailingAddress": ."` when run inside SQL CLR, while the second one does not?

In particular, the TSQL error is `"Msg 10329, Level 16, State 49, Line 1 .Net Framework execution was aborted."`

```
.method public hidebysig static bool CheckMailingAddress(valuetype [System.Data]System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlString param0) cil managed
{
   .maxstack 8
    L_0000: ldarga.s param0
    L_0002: nop 
    L_0003: nop 
    L_0004: call instance bool [System.Data]System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlString::get_IsNull()
    L_0009: brfalse L_0010
    L_000e: ldc.i4.1 
    L_000f: ret 
    L_0010: ldarga.s param0
    L_0012: nop 
    L_0013: nop 
    L_0014: call instance string [System.Data]System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlString::get_Value()
    L_0019: call class DatabaseValues.MailingAddress DatabaseValues.MailingAddress::op_Explicit(string)
    L_001e: pop 
    L_001f: ldc.i4.1 
    L_0020: ret 
}

.method public hidebysig static bool CheckMailingAddress(string param0) cil managed
{
   .maxstack 8
    L_0000: ldarg.0 
    L_0001: call class DatabaseValues.CheckMailingAddress DatabaseValues.CheckMailingAddress::op_Explicit(string)
    L_0006: pop 
    L_0007: ldc.i4.1 
    L_0008: ret 
}
```

Keep in mind, the MSIL is correct as as far as I know, because both of these methods work when called in a standalone app.  It's only when called inside SQL CLR that the first of the two crashes.  In the SQL CLR, the function is defined with the "nvarchar(4000)" type, which should play nice with SqlString as far as I know.

I could probably implement the first method using "string" as well and still do the null check, but it uses SqlString to take advantage of the INullable interface properties "IsNull" and "Value", because it's part of a generic code generator where other Sql* types could be used.

### SIMPLE PROBLEM SUMMARY:

For those distracted by the MSIL in the method body; ignore it.  I recompiled the functions to do nothing at all, and my point is that when "SqlString", rather than "string", is the input type, the CLR blows up and terminates with no error message, and the return value is NULL rather than TRUE.

```
//Crashes when input parameter is "SqlString"
.method public hidebysig static bool CheckMailingAddress(valuetype [System.Data]System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlString param0) cil managed
{
   .maxstack 8
    L_001f: ldc.i4.1 
    L_0020: ret 
}

//Doesn't Crash when input parameter is "string"
.method public hidebysig static bool CheckMailingAddress(string param0) cil managed
{
   .maxstack 8 
    L_0007: ldc.i4.1 
    L_0008: ret 
}
```

Comment: Have you tried attaching the Visual Studio debugger to this? Also, could you include the code in the original language (ie, C#, VB, etc), rather than MSIL?

Comment: MSIL is the original language.  Yes, I've attached the debugger.  It fails with no specific error message beyond what I've given and it doesn't hit any kind of breakpoint inside the CLR.

Comment: Wow dude - you're writing CLR procs in MSIL? Can I ask why? Have you tried having a look at what some compiled C# that does the same thing?

Comment: Yep! Unified data classes for apps and database. Single point of maintenance + speedy SQL CLR check constraint functions.

Comment: Specifically, my data classes have custom attribute tags that specify (TableName,FieldName,AllowNull) indicating the fields to which the check applies.  Finally, my DeployDatabaseAssembly project reflects the entire data class namespace, reads those attributes, generates the extremely efficient functions you see posted above in MSIL for each data class, merges them into the data class assembly with ILMerge, deploys the assembly to SQL server, creates the SQL CLR function wrappers for them, and finally strings them together, one boolean call per field, into a TSQL constraint for each table :)

Comment: So suppose the MailingAddress (subclass of my RegexConstrainedString class), applies to three different fields in three different tables.  It would have three instances of my custom "SqlFunctionCheck", that specify each of those tables/fields.  Additionally, if any one of those fields has AllowNull set to true, then the DeployDatabaseAssembly project will generate the CheckMailingAddress function with the MSIL that checks for a null value before attempting the explicit cast to MailingAddress (which would throw an error).  If null values are not required, then the simpler MSIL is generated.

Comment: The problem here, is that with the null-safe MSIL, the "SqlString" type is used instead of string, so that the INullable interface methods can be used, which is necessary because the DeployDatabaseAssembly project could generate functions for numeric types as well, in which case it would use SqlInt32, SqlBoolean, etc. which all implement the INullable interface... so the code uses that as a pattern for the null-safe MSIL (i.e. for any Sql* type, it calls INullable "get_IsNull" and "get_Value" to check for null and get the actual value if it goes on to check the value with the explicit cast.

Comment: Honestly though, I don't think there's anything wrong at all with the MSIL code.  I think maybe a recent patch to SQL Server introduced a bug that's causing problems marshalling data to the functions with the SqlString type, because these methods work fine outside SQL Server, and they used to work fine inside SQL Server.  The TSQL function interfaces for these have always used "nvarchar(4000)" as the parameter type, and the only thing that's different now in my database is that my fields are also "nvarchar(4000)" whereas they used to be "varchar(3000)".

Comment: "Unified data classes for apps and database" - say what? Could you explain how that's not possible with C#?

Comment: @Triynko: this is a claassic example of doing something the hard way!

Comment: @Mitch. "Only way" not "hard way".  To use a single C# Regex to constrain a data type in both an application and a database is to use the SQL CLR.  The only way to prevent invalid data from ever entering a database field is to have an active check constraint on the table that validates the field.  The only way to use an existing C# Regex is to have the check constraint call a CLR function that includes the Regex.  I've simply automated the deployment, so I don't have to maintain anything but that single definition in a C# file.  This has been working for OVER A YEAR; now it fails.

Comment: By using a C#/CLR-backed Regex constraint in the database, people can't even enter invalid data using SSMS, and that's the point.  I've enforced data integrity at the entry point to the database and use type-safe data classes throughout my application, so the data it handles is always valid.  And this is done by maintaining a single C# data class, and clicking a deploy button when I make changes.  There's no copying and pasting code or regular expressions or rewriting constraints in TSQL to match the C#.  It's unified and automated and (used to and mostly still does) work beautifully.

Comment: I just think the SQL CLR has a problem marshalling data to the SqlString type now for some reason.  You'll see.  I'll be watching for the bug report.

Comment: Also, as for why it's not written in C#... actually the generator is written in C#, and uses AssemblyBuilder.Emit calls to emit MSIL OpCodes.  That way I can use Reflection classes like MethodInfo and pass actual Type references to build these simple CLR functions.  The alternative would be concatenating type name strings into C# code and dynamically compiling it, which is just overkill to run parsers and validators for something so simple I can just emit the OpCodes directly and cleanly.

Comment: @Triynko: if it seems too hard, it usually is.

Comment: @Mitch.  It's not hard at all, that's your opinion.  This is extremely simple to me.  It worked for over a year.  You guys are getting distracted by the MSIL; ignore that.  The MSIL doesn't really matter, and I only posted it as a reference for anyone with in-depth SQL CLR knowledge.  My point was that it's crashing ONLY because "SqlString" is the input parameter type.  Even if all the method does is return true, it crashes when the input type is SqlString, but not when it's string, and it shouldn't do that.

Comment: Perhaps someone elses words are clear.  See PDF here: http://www.mediafire.com/?g1j6db15cq7lgu3  Scroll to page three to read "Wrapping Code to Promote Cross-Tier Reuse".  That's basically what I'm doing, except I've automated the process so I don't have to hand-write the wrappers that use the Sql* types and forward them to my data classes for verification.

Comment: @Triynko: you keep believing that! lol :)

Comment: @Mitch:  It is easy.  I was hoping I could convince you, but like anything it only appears complex when you don't understand it.  All I did was build a small app to automatically generate a function like this: bool CheckMailingAddress(string field_from_db) {(MailingAddress)field_from_db;return true;}, deploy the assembly it's packaged into, and create the function in TSQL.  The CheckMailingAddress wrapper is called from database constraints, which throw an error when the cast to MailingAddress fails, and returns true otherwise.  It's simple and fast.

Comment: It's capable of applying a .NET Regex to 1.5 million rows of nvarchar(4000) data in under 15 seconds, and it's far faster than anything that could ever be written in TSQL to perform the same check, in a check constraint.

Comment: The TSQL check constraints (also automatically generated and deployed) look like this: "([dbo].[CheckEmailAddress]([Email])=(1) AND [dbo].[CheckMailingAddress]([Address])=(1) AND [dbo].[CheckPhoneNumber]([Phone])=(1))", and it's ridiculously fast.

Comment: Fixed it!  At some point I switched my DeployDatabaseAssembly to target .NET 4.0.  I switched it back to .NET 3.5 and the SqlString isn't giving me problems anymore!  So now I'm trying to figure out whether I can switch the project back to v4.0 for the code generation process, but generate a DLL targeting .NET 3.5 assemblies.  Perhaps I can acquire type references differently than "typeof(SqlString)" like "Assembly.LoadFrom("v3.5\System.Data.dll").GetType("System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlString"), or set some options in AssemblyBuilder or call DefineDynamicAssembly on a AppDomain created for .NET 3.5.

Answer (score 5):

I found the source of the problem, and was able to resolve it, but I'm not sure about the details.

At some point I switched my DeployDatabaseAssembly project to target .NET 4.0, and AssemblyBuilder must have generated an assembly that targets .NET 4.0 as well.  Switching the project to target .NET 3.5 fixed the problem.

What's funny is the source DLL (database.dll) that contains all my datatypes is still targetting .NET 3.5, and was left that way intentionally because I knew SQL Server only supports CLR 2.0 right now, which effectively makes it incompatible with .NET 4.0, because .NET 4.0 seems to require CLR 4.0.  Using ILMerge, I was combining the dynamic assembly containing the generated functions with my existing (.NET 3.5) database.dll.  This ultimately resulted in hybrid assembly .NET 4.0 assembly that was mostly based on .NET 3.5 features and classes.  It's strange that I was able to get functions to work that used the basic "String" and "int" type parameters, but the SqlString type was causing crashes... obviously because it was being pulled from .NET 4.0 System.Data.dll, since it was referenced as "typeof(SqlString)" in my DeployDatabaseAssembly, which was targetting .NET 4.0.  It's just weird how that was crashing without any kind of error message or without any kind of warnings about it being incompatible with the loaded SQL CLR modules.

I wish I knew a way to force AssemblyBuilder running in a .NET 4.0 app to generate an assembly targeting .NET 3.5...

### Update: Problem thoroughly solved

I focused on the output of ILMerge and went ahead and switched the DeployDatabaseAssembly back to .NET 4.0.  By the way, I use ILMerge as a reference in my project, since it's a .NET assembly.

By setting the ILMerge option like this:

```
ILMerge merger = new ILMerge();
merger.SetTargetPlatform( "v2", @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v3.5\Profile\Client");
```

The resulting DLL deploys to SQL Server (as it did before), but it actually runs without errors this time.

Interestingly, if I replace just the "v3.5" in the target platform path with "v4.0" and try to deploy the assembly to SQL Server, then I get a **useful error message immediately during deployment "CREATE ASSEMBLY for assembly 'my assembly name' failed because the assembly is built for an unsupported version of the CLR runtime."**.  It's odd that when I wasn't setting any target platform at all, it would deploy fine, but was crashing without any error message.

This table summarizes the above configuration combinations and results:
[image]

Comment: It doesn't surprise me that the problem ended up being outside of the code that you posted. But as a side note, have you considered the fact that someone else will likely have to maintain this? Unless your performance requirements are that it's gotta be absolute-killer speed, I'd recommend doing it in C# for the simple fact that there are more people who can read/write C# than can read/write MSIL. You might be leaving a pretty big chunk of incredibly hard to understand code for your company's next developer. Then again, if it's really a requirement, that's the price that has to be paid.

Comment: It's gotta be absolute-killer speed, and emitting MSIL directly ensures there's no compiler in the mix injecting less-than-optimal code under any circumstance.  The program is actually written entirely in C#, and uses the ILGenerator class and its Emit method to emit MSIL op-codes (System.Reflection.Emit.OpCodes enum), so one never actually has to deal with MSIL syntax.  The posted MSIL was obtained by opening the generated assembly in .NET Reflector.

Comment: As for consideration for other developers... do you realize that the whole purpose of this utility is to make things easier for them.  While the utility itself is complicated, it's not something that's meant to be updated, because it's really a finished development tool and it's something I'd personally support or release as open-source.  It wraps a lot of complicated functionality relating to querying various types of functions in SQL Server, creating those functions, handling mappings from .NET to SQL data types, deploying assemblies, creating/disabling/enabling/checking constraints, etc.

Comment: With this utility, developers can create a new data class with a header like this: "public sealed class Username: RegexConstrainedString", and tag it with an attribute like this "[SqlFunctionCheck(Table="Users",Field="Username")]".  Then, by simply running this utility, it will automatically do the following for them: generate a new optimized assembly, deploy it to the database replacing old assembly, create "CheckUsername" SQLCLR function, create check constraint on the table (combining calls to that function and any others tagged to be applied to the same table), and recheck all constraints.